# How should I restructure my URLs to make development easier while preserving SEO?

Tags: seo, migration, clean-urls

I am trying to fix the URL structure of an ecommerce site that has about 90k part pages. The site has no URL directory structure. Thus, all 90k pages are under the root like `example.com/part-page-one`.

I'm not an SEO, but I do know this is incorrect and needs to be fixed for development purposes and SEO. Whatever change I make needs to keep SEO in mind first. There are 6 main part sections to the site:

(comments after `#`)

```
1. example.com/parts #defines a basic parts landing page
2. example.com/car-parts #this displays links to cart part category pages
3. example.com/catalogsearch #this searches the product database
4. example.com/some-category-name #this page would display parts specific to the category
5. example.com/part-page #this is a page featuring a single part and it may be a car, truck, or motorcycle part.
6. example.com/vehicle-page #this page has not been added to the site yet, but this page will feature parts that go to a specific vehicle.
```

So, I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to structure the urls in a hierarchy. The example.com/car-parts page is one of our highest ranking pages which causes some difficulty to the structure below.

1. Put all parts related pages under `example.com/parts`.
2. Put category related pages under `example.com/parts/category-name`
   Should this be `example.com/parts/categories/my-category-name`? What should be done with the `/parts/categories` page? We have several pages such as `example.com/serpentine-belts` that rank well but that only follows the flat URL structure which is very difficult to scale.
3. Put search under `example.com/parts/search`. I would like to use our search facets to link over to certain categories or brands pages.
4. Put vehicle part pages under `example.com/parts/vehicles/ford-f150`
   What should I do with `example.com/parts/vehicles`? Show a searchable list of vehicles? Redirect to somewhere home page?
5. Put part pages under `example.com/parts/my-part-page`

These are just a few ideas that I had but I am not sure what the best approach is going to be.

Comment: "I'm not an SEO, but I do know this is incorrect and needs to be fixed" -- I do a lot of SEO and it looks fine to me.  The more stuff in the URL the harder it is for users to figure it out.   The existing URL structure looks ideal to me from a usability and SEO standpoint.    As far as development goes, it could be a problem, but not necessarily.  What development problems do you have (or are you worried about)?

Comment: The site is built in Ruby on Rails which uses a routes file. Usually you specify certain routes(patterns of URLs) to go to a specific function in the server side code. So for example /parts would show all parts, /parts/:category/:category_name would show a specific category. However, because none of the URLS hold any kind of pattern and all 90k are randomly thought up, I have had to hard code about 2500 routes and then use my remaining Product database as a catch-all which 404s if a product with a certain URI isn't found. I could do this in 10 lines of code if there was a sensible structure.

Comment: For SEO, you will need to continue to support all existing URLs even after you move them.  If you change the URLs, you will need to redirect them to their new location.   So even if you change to make development easier, you are going to have to maintain a mapping of the old URLs to the new.